# How to Append Files with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have tried Flatten Hierarchy, Merge Files and Preserve Hierarchy in my attempts to Append or Merge files with Data Factory, but it will neither Append or Merge
[image]

The Sink looks like the following:

[image]

Can someone let me know how to configure Data Factory to merge files please

Comment: In the above it will copy the files to same folder individually one by one. you cannot merge the files in that forEach. To Merge, first generate all individual files using above loop then outside loop use a copy activity(give datasets folder path) with merge option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To merge the files, use the copy activity after the ForEach loop.

***First copy the individual files from REST to ADLS folder using the above loop. Then use another copy activity with source (give the datasets folder path).***

Use Wildcard path. Here I have used csv for sample.

[image]

Now in sink, use merge option.

[image]

files with same structure from REST API copied to ADLS folder.

[image]

Final csv file after merging.

[image]